# Updating UITableView rows and sections

Tags: ios, swift

I use a *tableview* in a *view*, and I want to dynamically change number of rows in each section by different events. I define an array by which I handle this with `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` functions and between them I use `deleteRows()` or `insertRows()` but, when I use this rows of *tableview* doesn't move and previous rows are maintained.

I did this work before and it worked properly, but now I don't know why this doesn't work. can anyone help me?

Comment: See this example, i hope it's help you https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-enums-and-uitableview-sections-1806b74b8138

Comment: Without seeing your code, noone can help you apart from offering guesses.

Comment: You should share code

Answer (score 0):

what's the requirement of beginUpdates() and endUpdates() in your code, If you want to add or remove row (deleteRows() or insertRows()) in specific section then Just add your record into array and reload tableview.

See this basic example for multiple section and row, i hope it's help you https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-enums-and-uitableview-sections-1806b74b8138

Answer (score 0):

You can add delete rows in UITableView as follows :

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
// Remove existing row
<designatedModel>.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

// Add new row
<designatedModel>.insert(object, at: indexPath.row)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```